# MIPS nested function the program is dropped off bottom

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am not an expertise in MIPS, sorry. I need to import a integer value between 0 and 5 (0 < n < 5). For example, if the value of n is > 4 I have an error message `errorDimensionMessage`and my program restart the function `jal dimension` until the right value is typed. After this, if I type a correct value (e.g., 3) the program goes in `jal exit`to exit.

(code updated)

The problem is after 5 (error) -> 3 (OK) the program is dropped off bottom.

```
.data
    InsertDimension: .asciiz " Insert an integer (n) with value between 0 and 5 (0 < n < 5): "
    errorDimensionMessage: .asciiz  " Error. Matrix dimension is not valid (e.g., 0 < n < 5)\n"
    messageExit: .asciiz " Exit...\n"


.text
.globl main
    main:
        jal dimension
        jal exit

   exit: 
        la $a0, messageExit 
        li $v0, 4 # print string
        syscall
        li $v0, 10 # loads the service that exits
        syscall

    dimension:
        move $s0, $ra # save return address into s0
        la $a0, InsertDimension 
        li $v0, 4 # print string
        syscall 
        li $v0, 5 # read an integer from console and put it in $v0!
        syscall
        jal isValidDimension
        move $ra, $s0    #restore return address that was saved into s0
        jr $ra #return

    isValidDimension: 
        move $s1, $s0 # save return address into s0
        beqz $v0, errorDimension
        bgt $v0, 4, errorDimension
        move $s0, $s1 # save return address into s0
        jr $ra #return

    errorDimension:
        la $a0, errorDimensionMessage 
        li $v0, 4 # print string
        syscall
        j dimension # return to dimension
```

Answer (score 2):

`jal dimension # return to dimension` That's not the correct way to jump back to `dimension`. You want to use a regular unconditional jump instead, i.e. the `J` instruction (or `B`).

What happens now is that that `jal` changes `$ra` to point to the address of the instruction following the `jal`, i.e. past the end of your program. So when `jr $ra` in `dimension` is executed you jump past the end of your program, hence why you get *"the program is dropped off bottom"*.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. I updated the code using neasted function but still not clear your help.

Comment: Well, like I said, `jal` is not the correct instruction to use here. You should use a regular jump, or possibly `jr $ra`.

Comment: if I use jr $ra, the program reurn to jal exit while I need to back in dimension

Comment: Then use `J` or `B` like I suggested in my answer. `JAL` modifies `$ra`. Unless you _want_ that as a side effect there's no reason to use it over `J`/`B`.